# Asp.net client side database or datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, datatables, client-side

I am working on this project which I have to process large amount of data using asp.net mvc, I have an idea that instead of using webserver memory why can't we use client side memory to store and query those data for faster performance, I am trying to find the solution.somebody please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

We use this JQuery plug-in:
https://datatables.net/

Here is an example with MVC:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Hi Scott, using this example we can display data, but I want to query those data in client side instead of server side

Comment: That sounds like terrible user experience. Though I am intrigued if you figure out a way to do that. Please post your solution here if you find one.  

I posted the datatables thing because you do not have to query the database. You can pump data in via JSON that you have precompiled. From there you could abuse the plug-in to filter results. It would be pretty ugly. 

https://jsfiddle.net/a5r4b9hf/1/

Comment: I done this using help of Alasql where we can bring the data from server to client machine , we can query it client machine , this is much faster than i expected